# Save different data settings with C# (variables) not as plain text easy in a specific filepath and access easy

Tags: c#, file, save, compression

How do I save my data...

- (compressed/encrypted) not human readable  in a portable file by
- influencing on directory name and file name  with using easily
- addressable settings by "name" and "value" like in registry/ini
- with the possibility to access the same one settings file (machine based)
- with any executable

In VB I did that with INI Files, but now I have heard from MS that the Framework offers no function to access INI Files anymore. Since INI Files are also not any longer up-to-date for using them in a new application I wanted something similar. Just to write to a text file line by line is not what I want to do, I will explain why: If I will need a setting named "Label4" I have to read the entire file and search for the line containing it and then I have even to split the result in setting name and setting value (.NET has another syntax split function).

Let's say I have a thousand labels and a hundred textboxes in a form and wanna save its content easily to a file or whatever and read it the same easily back addressing the settings by a name already how would I do that? I am ready to use a DB but don't know how to setup and save information there. Easy would be to access the registry with "name" and "value", but I prefer a portable file.

The data shall be stored compressed or encrypted not in a plain text human readable way (I mean XML / html is not what I search for to store the data else I could research again how to use INI files with C# which might be possible I guess). I stumbled upon "application settings" but this doesn't save my data compressed nor can I simply influence on path and filename of the settings file. With each new EXE all the stored settings are lost again for those new EXE if I have used "application settings". I need not "user/application based" settings but "machine based", I hope you understand what I wanna say. Any App on my comp shall be able to get to my settings file
and I shall be able to choose the place/filename where to save the settings.

Comment: Dude. Seriously. Use paragraphs. =)

Comment: You must love punishing yourself. o.o

Comment: Well, I tried to break it up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write to any xml file and get your desired results.

1. (compressed/encrypted) not human readable in a portable file

   ```
     You can both encrypt/compress a normal file
   ```
2. influencing on directory name and file name with using easily

   ```
     Can't understand what you mean
   ```
3. addressable settings by "name" and "value" like in registry/ini

   ```
     xml gives you flexibility you need
   ```
4. with the possibility to access the same one settings file (machine based)

   ```
     You can keep it machine based.
   ```
5. with any executable

   ```
     What does it mean?
   ```

Comment: @feedwall You can encrypt it and then save it. Decrypt and read as xml.